# Adding a External Folder to the ClassPath in a runnable jar

Tags: java, maven

I have a maven project where I create a jar with dependencies using maven assembly plugin. I also have an external config file ( conf.properties ) that is required by the jar to work properly.

My project structure is like this:

```
  |- abc.jar
  |- config
     |-conf.properties
```

How can I add this config folder to the classpath of the jar file? I tried to do this using `-cp` command and manipulating class-path property in `MANIFEST.MF` file but no luck so far.

Does anyone know a way to do this?

Comment: see [Class-Path Attribute](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/specs/jar/jar.html#class-path-attribute) (as I understand it, `Class-Path: config/` is needed (ended by a newline character))

Comment: I tried that but did not work

Comment: just tested *no maven*, works - 1) `java -jar abc.jar`; 2) `Class-Path: config/` must end with slash; 3) empty line at end of manifest  ((maybe you could write how you are launching the JAR, how accessing the file, and show the content of the MANIFEST.MF))

Comment: to clarify, is the config file inside the conf folder? It's possible that the file is not in the assumed location

Comment: How are you trying to read `conf.properties`?

Answer (score 1):

This is how I tested (sorry, no maven)!

Main class:

```java
package cfh.sf.Chamika;

import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class ABC {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("conf");
        System.out.println(bundle.getString("test"));
    }
}
```

Manifest file, note empty line at end (entries must end with a newline (CR, LF or CRLF)):

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: cfh.sf.Chamika.ABC
Class-Path: config/
```

Directory structure

```
dist/
    abc.jar
    config/
        conf.properties
```

Content of `conf.properties`:

```
test = OK, it is working!
```

Executed with

```
java -jar abc.jar
```

---

Alternative, not using `ResourceBundle`:

```java
package cfh.sf.Chamika;

import java.io.IOException;

public class ABC {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (var input = ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("conf.properties")) {
            int ch;
            while ((ch = input.read()) != -1) {
                System.out.print((char) ch);
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```